# BGCOLOR only latest occurrence of a condition

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to only apply bgcolor on latest occurrence of a condition?

for example:

```
r = close == high
bgcolor(r ? #cc0000 : na)
```

in the above case all occurrences where close equals high would get applied with the bgcolor. But what is required is only to bgcolor latest occurrence.

any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks/sudharshan

Answer (score 1):

This script should do the trick

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
n = bar_index
val = n - valuewhen(close == high,n,0)
bgcolor(#2157f3,offset=-val,show_last=1)
```

That's how I would do it.